# Gradle proxy settings

Tags: gradle, proxy

How can I set Gradle to use the system proxy, instead of defining a specific one?

A specific host can be easily defined using gradle.properties, but I want the one used by IE/Chrome to be used. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried it myself but you could try setting the `java.net.useSystemProxies` system property

eg: `gradlew -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true taskX`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the `useSystemProxies` setting on the command line, you can set it in your *gradle.properties* file:

```
systemProp.java.net.useSystemProxies=true
```